# How to count the number of items in multidimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a variable like so (it's dynamically generated so this is just an example of its data structure):

```
this.arrayIHave = [[1,2,"123"],[145,1,4],["erg","era",23],[1,2,3],["12","Qwd","edwed12"]]
```

The # of items in each array (e.g. [1,2,"123"]) within the parent array (this.arrayIHave) will always be the equal to each other. How can I figure out how many items are in the arrays within the array?

In the example above the number I'm looking for is 3 since in each of the child arrays there are 3 elements. (a for loop I believe would give me 3,3,3,3,3 etc. however I'm just looking to get the length as one number)

I've tried

```
this.arrayIHave.length
```

However it only gives me the number of arrays within the array (5 - as it should) - however is there a way to do something like this to the 'child' arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the number of items (length of the array) by doing `this.arrayIHave[0].length`.

However, if `this.arrayIHave` is potentially an empty array, calling the previous method will throw an error, a solution to that is to iterate throught the array using the `.reduce` function:

```js
this.arrayIHave
  .reduce(
    (previousLength, subArray) => subArray.length, // Get the length of each sub-array
    0 // The number of elements per sub-array (by default, if the main array is empty, the sub-arrays are empty too)
  );
```

EDIT: Renamed parameters to make them easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Access the length of the first array?

```
this.arrayIHave[0].length
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array inside of the parent array are gonna be always the same length between each other you could do:

```
this.arrayIHave[anynumber].length;
```

For example the first one:

```
this.arrayIHave[0].length;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array contains arrays of the same length then you can just get the length of one array and that will be your answer, like `arrayIHave[0].length` or `arrayIHave[1].length` and so on